# Can't access Ref from useEffect using "this.refname.current"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm missing something simple here, I need to access a defined Ref within a `useEffect` . The debugger shows that `this` is undefined and therefore I can't do `this.refOverlay.current;`.

```
// Ref
const refOverlay = useRef(null); 

// Sample useEffect that references it
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.mode === 'new') {
        let b = this; // Undefined
        let a = this.refOverlay.current; // Error on this line
        if (a) {
            console.log('ok');
        }
    }
}, [props.mode]);

...
return (
{/* JSX Definition */}
        <OverlayTrigger ref={refOverlay} trigger="click" rootClose placement="bottom" overlay={popoverApprover}>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="more-info">TEST</a>
        </OverlayTrigger> 
);
```

Comment: You don’t need `this`, the variable is in the same scope in arrow functions so you should be able to just use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such `this` in  the function component.

```
  const Title = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (ref.current) {
        ref.current.WHATEVERYOUWANTHERE
      }
    }, [])
  }
```

NOTE: couple of difference between class and function component

- function component has no this, it's a function
- function component is only the render function
- to have state, you need `useState`
- to have any persistent storage, you need hook

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a functional based component. Which doesn't have the `this`
Simply remove the `this` keyword and you're fine.